# \newcommand on several commands with \begin{comment}

Tags: macros

I'm trying to short comment command :

```
\begin{flagA}
    \chapter*{Revision }
    \input{chapters/revisiony}
\end{flagA}
```

to :

```
\flagB{
    \chapter*{Revision }
    \input{chapters/revisiony}
    }
```

I tried to define :

```
\newcommand{\flagB}[1]{ \begin{flagA} #1 \end{flagA}}
```

But I get error:

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\flagB ->\endgroup
```

Comment: `\flag1` isn't a valid command name (no numbers are allowed in normal command names). Try `\flagA`.

Comment: flag1 is only an example , I use other name (w/o numbers)

Comment: The command version should be easier, at the simplest `\newcommand{\omit}[1]{}`. Then you could define the environment using that: `\usepackage{environ} \NewEnviron{omit}{\omit{\BODY}}`